# How to change the Resgen command line in a VS.NET project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tracker, resgen

Having an issue with a [ResGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) call during a build of a .NET 2.0 project from within Visual Studio .NET 2010, [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/e5900710-9849-4d10-aa28-48b734d06bf2) suggests:

> Add this to your MSBUILD command-line:
>   `/p:ResGenExecuteAsTool=true;ResGenToolArchitecture=ManagedIL;ResGenTrackerSdkPath="%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64"`

I've searched for hours without success trying to find a way to do this from within my Visual Studio .NET project.

**Therefore my question is:**

How can I change the MSBUILD command line of a .NET 2.0 (class library) project in Visual Studio 2010?

I have no fear changing my ".csproj" file, I would prefer *not* to change MSBuild files that were shipped with Visual Studio, if this is possible.

**Update and solution:**

Thanks to Oded's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354625/how-to-change-the-resgen-command-line-in-a-vs-net-project#comment16590033_12354625) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12354819/107625), I added the following two lines:

```
<ResGenTrackerSdkPath>%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64</ResGenTrackerSdkPath>
<TrackFileAccess>false</TrackFileAccess>
```

right inside the very first `<PropertyGroup>` section of my ".csproj" file (i.e. after line 3). This made the file compile successfully!

I now check and see whether it also *runs* successfully.

Comment: You should be able to simply add these as properties in the project file. `<ResGenTrackerSdkPath>%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64</ResGenTrackerSdkPath>` etc...

Comment: Wonderful, that did it! Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all properties in MSBuild, what you can pass in through the command line can be added in the project file in XML elements instead.

For example:

```
<ResGenTrackerSdkPath>%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64</ResGenTrackerSdkPath>
```

And:

```
<ResGenExecuteAsTool>true</ResGenExecuteAsTool>
```

etc...