# MSBuild only errors on a handful of projects

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration

We have migrated to TFS2012 and VS2012 with an existing solution. My old build controller and TFS used to be on Windows 7, however this server for TFS2012 and our build controller is now Windows 8. The build is giving me the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (2401): Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the
>   registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed

I have seen that a potential fix could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907056/1288553) however the error above is only occurring in specific projects. I thought that this could be down to the .NET framework version, however most projects are on the same version as other projects.

I then did a compare of the project files and noticed that the following attribute was a lower value than a project that worked.

```
<OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
```

So I updated this to version 4.0 and I still have no luck. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a work around which doesn't involve me any installations? There must be a setting of some sort that is different as some projects do build and some do not...

*TIA*.

Comment: Lc.exe is normally installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools.  Sure, only a few projects would use the license compiler.  The v8 SDK made a bit of a mess, the DevDiv and Windows groups don't seem to be talking to each other much anymore.  Run regedit.exe and search for "WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86".  Document where you found it.  It otherwise sounds like a place-holder string that should have been substituted during install.

Comment: @HansPassant I have reluctantly installed VS2010 onto the build controller server which has solved the issue, thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys you know really simple solution.  go to asp.net and install the asp.net and tools from downloads page.

[htp://www.asp.net/downloads](http://www.asp.net/downloads)

and every thing will be set and working.