# Task could not find "LC.exe" using SdkToolsPath

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have cloned a project to my computer using TFS, when I build the project I get this error :

> Error 6   Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the
>   registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed

I have searched the web but couldn't find a solution. I use VS 2013 and .NET 4.
How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: From reading the error message, there is no environment variable called `SdkToolsPath`, or it does exist and the value is empty. So set that value, or fix the registry value.

Comment: _"Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and **that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed**"_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731365/running-msbuild-fails-to-read-sdktoolspath

Answer (score -4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha0k3c9f(v=vs.110).aspx

> The License Compiler reads text files that contain licensing
>   information and produces a binary file that can be embedded in a
>   common language runtime executable as a resource. A .licx text file is
>   automatically generated or updated by the Windows Forms Designer
>   whenever a licensed control is added to the form. As part of
>   compilation, the project system will transform the .licx text file
>   into a .licenses binary resource that provides support for .NET
>   control licensing. The binary resource will then be embedded in the
>   project output. **Cross compilation between 32-bit and 64-bit is not
>   supported when you use the License Compiler when building your
>   project.** This is because the License Compiler has to load assemblies,
>   and loading 64-bit assemblies from a 32-bit application is not
>   allowed, and vice versa. In this case, use the License Compiler from
>   the command line to compile the license manually, and specify the
>   corresponding architecture. **This tool is automatically installed with
>   Visual Studio**. To run the tool, use the Developer Command Prompt (or
>   the Visual Studio Command Prompt in Windows 7). For more information,
>   see Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: I don't understand how this quote answers the question. Can you add a summary or explanation?

Comment: Theres a world of Info there. are you building x86 v x64. what control in your project requires licencing. it was hard to tell from your question if you knew what LC.exe did, and how it related to the project you have cloned. add some more detail and I maybe able to expand

Comment: I don't find this quote helpful at all. For me the problem didn't even have to do with LC.exe, but SdkToolsPath not being set. Furthermore, some of us are trying to compile projects without Visual Studio being installed.

Comment: Although OP has accepted this answer, it doesn't actually answer the question, nor does provide enough details on how to solve the problem. It is a mere copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using MSBuild.exe to build projects from the command line, you can pass TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory as a parameter to avoid having to edit your .csproj files.
For example:
`MSBuild.exe mysolution.sln /t:build /p:TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools"`

Answer (score 5):

It turns out you can specify the path to the SDK directly in the .csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>
```

and the build found lc.exe that way.
So do a dir /s for lc.exe and use that path.

I previously expected to set this using `<SdkToolsPath>`, but that didn't work. In Microsoft.Common.targets, SdkToolsPath gets set from `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory`, so I tried that and it worked. (It would be nice if the variable name corresponded 1 to 1, but they don't.)

This is on Visual Studio 2015, and msbuild being called from ant.

Comment: where in .targets did you put that line ?

Comment: also looks like .targets file is locked out from writing even for administrators hmmm

Comment: Where in the csproj should this be added? Under which heading?

Comment: <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: i.e. put it under a <PropertyGroup> tag under the main <Project> tag

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and resolved it by re-installing the Visual Studio.