# TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory - where to add in project file?

Tags: msbuild, projects-and-solutions

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103582/task-could-not-find-lc-exe-using-sdktoolspath) answer, It says to add

```
<TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>
```

to the `CSProj` file.

I cannot find where in the csproj file to add it -where do I add it please? Under which heading?

Answer (score 0):

It should be added under a `<PropertyGroup>` tag under the main `<Project>` tag according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103582/task-could-not-find-lc-exe-using-sdktoolspath#comment75158568_39649495) comment

It also worked for me