# Where is TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory defined in web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

I'm having the same problem as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442450/why-is-visual-studio-2013-using-the-wrong-sdktoolspath-for-lc-exe) have but with a twist: It's a web project without a project file.

So, given this error message:

> C:\MySolution\My.Project.Web\licenses.licx: Could not transform licenses file into a binary resource.  Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\lc.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

(There is indeed no "file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\lc.exe", but there is a subdirectory in "bin" called "NETFX 4.5.1 Tools" where lc.exe is. Moving its contents to "bin" had no effect)

Where can I define TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory in web.config so I can point it to the correct path?

Using: Windows 10 64x, Visual Studio Community Edition 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.config you can define alongside the TargetFrameworkVersion, something like this (my example from .NET 4.6.2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AssemblyName>xxx</AssemblyName>
      <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
      <TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>
      ... etc ...
    </PropertyGroup>
... etc ...
```

Assume it works the same for .NET 4.5 and web.config.

See also [Task could not find "LC.exe" using SdkToolsPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103582/task-could-not-find-lc-exe-using-sdktoolspath)