# Build missing SDK

Tags: c#, winapi, teamcity

I'm using Teamcity to run a build, getting the following error:
"Could not find "LC.exe"
Make sure the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed 
(Registry key:..\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.6\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86")"

Tried installing SDK from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34860, didnt work.

Teamcity Version: 9.1.1,
Windows server 2012

I have .net 4.6.1 installed on the server. I do not want to install VS2010 as it is build agent. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: This doesn't help.
When I run-> regedit.exe, I do not see a microsoft sdk folder under Hkey_local_machine->Software->Microsoft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running MSBuild fails to read SDKToolsPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731365/running-msbuild-fails-to-read-sdktoolspath)