# MSBuild assigns wrong TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory

Tags: .net, msbuild

A fresh dev machine fails to build our .net-framework-3.5-project on VS2019. Here's a dump of our investigation so far.

1. Diffing a verbose log from this machine against a working machine, we get this line early in the log, only on the failing machine:

> ```
> Property reassignment: $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\ Microsoft.NETFramework.CurrentVersion.props (90,5)
> ```

2. As a result (?) many times later in the log the failing machine shows

> ```
> TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\
> ```

While a working machine shows

```
TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
```

3. Looking into Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.props, the relevant lines show -

> ```
> <TargetingClr2Framework Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v2.0' or '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.0' or '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5'">true</TargetingClr2Framework>
> <MSBuildManagedCompilerPath Condition="'$(TargetingClr2Framework)' == 'true'">$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot)\v3.5</MSBuildManagedCompilerPath >
> <TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory Condition="'$(TargetingClr2Framework)' == 'true'">$(SDK35ToolsPath)</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>
>
> <!-- If the sdk path is not 3.5 or lower set it to the 40 sdk tools path. This will allow future target framework versions to use the 4.0 sdk tool set
>          When a new windows SDK revs they will inplace update the location pointed to by this property. When a new sdk is release this target will have to be
>          revised along with another toolsversion. -->
> <TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)' == '' ">$(SDK40ToolsPath)</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>
> ```

So it seems like for some reason the failing machine didn't catch the TargetFrameworkVersion value of this project as v3.5.

4. Not sure the choice of a toolset should have made any difference, but it does ([probably a different bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/627744/tlbimp-doesnt-respect-referencemscorlib.html)).
5. The MSBuild registry keys and VS2019/MSBuild folders are identical on working and failing machines.

Before we [go reinstalling multiple VS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739132/89706) - does anyone have an idea what might be causing it or how to diagnose deeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumping my findings here, in case it helps someone some day.

[MSBuild is open source](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild), and skimming it it seems to contain many, many extra tracing facilities.  They're triggered by environment variables - probably since they're intended to be used across multiple MSBuild processes.  Here's a (partial) list of ones that were useful for me:

1. MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE=1    - avoids spawning multiple processes, helps debugging.
2. MSBUILDENABLEDEBUGTRACING=1  - enables multiple internal `Trace.WriteLine` calls
3. MSBUILDDEBUGEVALUATION = 1   - some more `Trace.WriteLine`s, around some Project property evaluation methods(`IsDirty`, `Set`\ `Remove` `GlobalProperty`)
4. MSBUILDDEBUG = 1             - enables many Console.WriteLine calls, mostly around cache management.
5. MSBUILDDEBUGONSTART  =2  - waiting to attach debugger,
                        =1  - launch new debugger.
6. MSBUILDDEBUGSCHEDULER=1  - *lots* of high detail messages, around BuildRequest management. Dumped to EngineTrace_{processId}.txt file, by default in Path.GetTempPath() and can be overriden by MSBUILDDEBUGPATH.

There are probably many ways to intercept these messages even without building from source. What I did was load the MSBuild executable into VS and run it - so (1) I saw all the messages in the output pane, (2) whenever I broke into a function VS downloaded the matching CS source for me (you need to enable source server + source link for this, under Tools/Options/Debugging/General).

I also did a lot of diffing of message dumps between a working machine and the failing one. In our case the problem was a bad uninstall of a previous VS build, but that probably has less interest to you.