# MSBuild on CI Server can't find AL.exe

Tags: winapi, .net-4.0, msbuild, teamcity

I'm having a problem on my TeamCity CI build server where during compilation I get the following error:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2342, 9): error MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

I've found similar reports from a year ago when people were upgrading to .NET 3.5, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109955/task-failed-because-al-exe-was-not-found). In that case, installing the latest SDK solved the issue, however I have already installed the latest SDK ([Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B&displaylang=en)) on my build server. The MSBuild tools are all there on the server, in a folder called

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

and AL.exe exists in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

However the registry key mentioned in the error message does not exist. So, it seems like there is something wrong with the installation/configuration of MSBuild. This error only happens for projects that have embedded resources, which require AL.exe.

Comment: This issue re-appeared for us today, after alst nights .NET patches, and we had to re-run the command in the accepted answer. Very strange!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As you have install the latest SDK (I'm assuming that's v7.1)

> 1. Go to "Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1" from the Start menu
> 2. Select "Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt" and enter
> 3. > cd Setup
> 4. > WindowsSdkVer -version:v7.1

This will tell msbuild to use that version of the tools without needing to do any scary registry editing.

Comment: That's very elegant, far better than my registry hack. How is a mere mortal supposed to know this stuff? PS. Since you thought my question was worth answering, please consider giving it an upvote.

Comment: This was half the solution on my server running Windows 2003 64bit. Msbuild was looking for the registry keys in the 32 bit part of the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node) and WindowsSdkVer is setting the 64 bit part. I had to manually update the paths in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0 to make this work.

Comment: The Windows SDK command line was removed in later versions of .NET. If you're using a msbuild proj file, try removing ToolsVersion from <MSBuild> task, it solved it for me. I guess instead of trying to use a specific (non-existing) SDK, it used the latest one installed.

Answer (score 18):

Even though the question is quite old but it still appears in the top of google search results so I decided to post my solution as well. I have trapped into same issue while during TeamCity setup on Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 Pro.

I have installed [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) and [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (Only tools for .NET 4.6.2) and got the error from question.

The missing puzzle was to set environment variable: `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools`.

After setting environment variable MSBuild was able to resolve all needed tools including AL.exe and build succeeded.

Please let me know if same can be achieved by setting values in registry, but otherwise environment variables also works very well in this case and no installation of VS is needed.

Comment: Are we walking about system environment variables here or build configuration settings -> Parameters? For the last an `env.` would be added prior to `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory`, right?

Comment: My comment is correct, adding that there solves the problem.

Comment: @CularBytes, I don't completely understand you first comment. I have added that environment variable to variables of user under which TC was running. It can also be added as system variable. And I am glad it helped.

Comment: I had a similar issue with TeamCity 2017.1 on Windows 2012 R2. I had the set the env value and then not until I restarted both Team City services was msbuild able to see the new variables.

Answer (score 6):

You also need to apply the following registry fix to update msbuild to point to the V7.1 sdk values.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0]
"MSBuildToolsPath"="C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\"
"MSBuildToolsRoot"="C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\"
"FrameworkSDKRoot"="$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1@InstallationFolder)"
"MSBuildRuntimeVersion"="4.0.30319"
"SDK40ToolsPath"="$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86@InstallationFolder)"
"SDK35ToolsPath"="$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\WinSDKNetFx35Tools@InstallationFolder)"
"MSBuildToolsPath32"="$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSBuild\\ToolsVersions\\4.0@MSBuildToolsPath)"
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem there, here's my simple answer to this.

After you have installed the Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 on the TeamCity Server.

**In Regedit Change this key**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0\SDK40ToolsPath
```

to

```
$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86@InstallationFolder)
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps. This worked perfectly to me. Saved my time.

1- Right-click the **My Computer** icon and choose **Properties**, or in Windows **Control Panel**, choose **System**.

2- Choose **Advanced system settings**.

3- On the **Advanced** tab, click **Environment Variables**.

4- Click **New** to create a new environment variable under *User variable section*.

5- Variable name:   **TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory**

6- Variable value: TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools

*Variable value depends on your SDK installation path.*
[image]

7- Click **OK** and **Save** all windows.

8- **Restart** Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple, effective fix.

The problem seems to be that the tools version delivered with Visual Studio is version 7.0A, while the version delivered with the Windows SDK is version 7.1. That's all very well, but MSBuild.exe is still looking for the version 7.0A registry keys, which don't exist. This has to be a bug!

Looking in my registry, all the information for V6.0 and V7.1 is present and correct. So my solution is simple. I created a registry link that makes an alias of the 7.1 keys.

It's not possible to create registry links using the built-in tools, so I downloaded a little utility called 'regln' from [here](http://www.tenox.tc/out/#regln).

> C:>regln-x86.exe "\Registry\Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A" "\Registry
>   \Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1"

Job done. MSBuild now works perfectly on the TeamCity server.

Answer (score 2):

Add a system env variable `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory`

like this:

`TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools`

restart VS

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue setting up a new build server on Windows 10.
Found and installed the latest (at the time) [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279) and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this problem trying to get our .Net 4.0 builds working. We found that the location of al.exe had changed between where the original MSBuild that came with .Net 4.0 looks, and the Visual Studio SDK for .Net 4.0 (which was released later).

Since the only standalone installation of the SDK tools available is the one we had already installed without success (the one you mentioned), the only solution we could think of was to install Visual Studio on the build agents. We put Visual Studio 2010 *Express* (to keep the installation as lightweight as possible) on there and the problem went away. Not a pretty solution, but it did work - installing VS2010 also installs the SDK tools of the specific version that MSBuild appears to be looking for.

This is a problem that really shouldn't happen, but there didn't seem to be a way of making MSBuild look in the correct place for the tools, even hacking around in the registry.

Comment: Unfortunately, installing Visual Studio on this server is probably out of the question. Thanks for the info, though.